# MongoDB: How do I get multiple $indexOfArray values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document where the index of an array holds meaning. In a MongoDB aggregation, How do I return ALL of the indices in an array that matches a specific value? $indexOfArray only returns the first item.

For example, with:

```
{ 
    data: [-1, 100, 150, 200, -1, -1] 
}
```

If I'm looking for -1, I would like to receive: [0, 4, 5].

Comment: `"$reduce"` is a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this

Can use `$filter` to filter an indices array ([0,1,2....N]). Each iteration(i) of the indices array is checked with the condition if the `data[i] == -1` and the ones that are equal are filtered out.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      indices: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$data" } ] },
          cond: { $eq: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", "$$this" ] }, -1 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jhPzijrXCDv)

using `$reduce`. Iterate through an indices array and add to the accumulator array if the condition is met

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      indices: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$data" } ] },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", "$$this" ] }, -1 ] },
              then: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this" ] ] },
              else: "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/60LEEJUN_Wn)